# how to insert subtract of each two subsequent rows and inserting it into a new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a question about writing query in sql.

in the picture 1 I want to subtract row 2 from row1 (in column date) and insert it's result in row1 of new column with the title of Recency. and again subtract row3 from row2 and insert it in row2 of the new column, and so on.

[picture 1](http://www.8pic.ir/images/14490285632526381013.jpg):

[image]

in fact I want to calculate the recency of each user's activity. for example in the following picture, I calculated this for one user(manually); I want to do this for all of the users by writing a query in sql.

[picture 2](http://www.8pic.ir/images/38478033832080790150.jpg):

[image]

..........................................................................................

and other question:

I also want to calculate the frequency of activity of each user before the current date. I want to calculate frequency for each row. for example for this example, for user abkqz we have:

```
user name     frequency
abkqz             4
abkqz             3
abkqz             2
abkqz             1
abkqz             0
```

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you.
I found the following link related to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366788/how-do-i-get-the-time-difference-between-each-subsequent-row-in-sql   but, when I run this query, it subtracts rows without considering user-name. in fact I want to group by user-name. and do this procedure for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the following table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [15853354] -- Stack Overflow question number
(
    [user-name] VARCHAR(20),
    [submissions] INT,
    [date] DATE,
    [score] NUMERIC(9,2),
    [points] NUMERIC(9,1)
)

INSERT [15853354]
VALUES
    ('abkqz', 5, '12 JUL 2010', 83.91, 112.5),
    ('abkqz', 5, '9 JUN 2010', 77.27, 0),
    ('abkqz', 5, '17 MAY 2010', 91.87, 315)
```

Then you could write the following query

```
;WITH [cte15853354] AS
(
    SELECT 
        [user-name],
        [submissions],
        [date],
        [score],
        [points],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [user-name], [date] DESC) AS [ROWNUMBER]
    FROM [15853354]
)
SELECT 
    t.[user-name],
    t.[submissions],
    DATEDIFF(DAY, ISNULL([t-1].[date],t.[date]),t.[date]) AS [recency],
    t.[score],
    t.[points]
FROM [cte15853354] t
LEFT JOIN [cte15853354] [t-1]
    ON [t-1].[user-name] = t.[user-name]
    AND [t-1].[ROWNUMBER] = t.[ROWNUMBER] + 1
```

This uses a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) to calculate a [row number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186734.aspx), and then does a self join to join each row with the next, and then calculates the date difference in days.

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: wow; great :) I write this query and got result ... thanks a lot ... do you have any idea about frequency?

Comment: Tom's query won't work correctly if there is more than one user, but it can easily be fixed with a PARTITION BY clause. In addition, the ROWNUMBER column can be used to find the Frequency you want. Here is the query with both changes: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e59c3/2

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve. but the order of frequency is reverse, and also it's value should be 1-value lower (we should not consider the current date). because frequency is the number of times that a user had activity before the current date. so I should have 2,1,0 instead of 1,2,3...   very sorry if I ask many questions, I'm new in sql.

Comment: @SteveKass, I'm not sure why you say it won't work with more than one user.  I've tried adding another user and it seems to work as expected.  Note the join clause includes [user-name].  If you could provide some more details that would be great.

Comment: @TomHunter My mistake - your query is fine. The PARTITION BY is only needed in order to for your row number column to give what the O.P. wants for [frequency]. Thanks for asking me to follow up.

Comment: @PotentialScientist I think you just need to reverse the row numbering by removing the DESC (and adjust the join accordingly). Does the following work? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e59c3/4

Comment: @ Steve Kass : great; I got result for frequency too. Thanks a lot :) @Steve Kass and @ Tom Hunter, Thanks a lot for your help, your prompt solutions, and your kindness; and also for following my comments :)  I don't know how to thank  you ...  Wish you the bests

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (untested, since sample data was only posted in a picture). The query users analytical function options that were introduced in SQL Server 2012, so this won't work on an earlier version.

```
select
  [user-name],
  submissions,
  score,
  datediff(day,
    lag([date],1) over (
      partition by [user-name]
      order by [date],
    [date]) as recency,
  count(*) over (
    partition by [user-name]
    order by [date] desc) -1 as frequency
from yourTable;
```

Comment: many many thanks :) but I had SQL 2008, I wish I had 2012; your code is very simple and short ... I'll try this if I purchase SQL 2012 .