# subtract values of two rows and inserting it into a new column (not subsequent rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

relevant to my previous question here: [how to insert subtract of each two subsequent rows and inserting it into a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853354/how-to-insert-subtract-of-each-two-subsequent-rows-and-inserting-it-into-a-new-c/15854174?noredirect=1#comment22590607_15854174)

I have another question. In the following table; I want to calculate the amount of time that have passed from each user's last winning in a competition. in fact I should subtract the last winning date from current date. (place=1) is indicative of winning.

the current table:

http://www.8pic.ir/images/75206897877200828586.jpg

the result that I want:

http://www.8pic.ir/images/78832309907063712878.jpg

I wrote the following query for this question (according to the answer that I got for my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853354/how-to-insert-subtract-of-each-two-subsequent-rows-and-inserting-it-into-a-new-c/15854174?noredirect=1#comment22590607_15854174)) ! but the problem is that I get many duplicate rows! I have only 4000 rows, but when I run this query I get 40,000 rows! what is the problem! would you please help me. and also I get negative value for the users that have not won before. I want these fields be NULL.

```
;WITH [cte15853354] AS
 (
    SELECT 
        [user-name],
        [submissions],
        [date],
        [place],
        [recency],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [user-name], [date] DESC) AS [ROWNUMBER]
    FROM dbo.[top-design1]
 )
SELECT 
    t.[user-name],
    t.[submissions],
    t.[date],
    t.[place],
    t.[recency],
    DATEDIFF(DAY, ISNULL(k.[date],t.[date]),t.[date]) AS [win-recency]
INTO dbo.[top-design2]
FROM [cte15853354] t
LEFT JOIN [cte15853354] k
    ON k.[user-name] = t.[user-name] 
     where k.[place]=1 
    ORDER BY t.[user-name], t.[date] DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go (and no need for the case testing, actually):

```
SELECT [user-name], 
       submissions,
       [date],
       place,
       recency,
       DATEDIFF(DAY, 
       (SELECT TOP(1) [date]
        FROM [top-design1] td1
        WHERE td1.[user-name] = [top-design1].[user-name]
        AND place = 1
        AND [date] < [top-design1].[date]
        ORDER BY [date] DESC), [date]) as recencywin
FROM [top-design1]
```

I suppose you can manage by yourself to use it for insert purposes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I don't know why I get this error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF' "

Comment: yeah, it misses an I, it's IIF.

Comment: I changed if command to the following and I got the result:           case when [date] > [lastdate] 
            then DATEDIFF(DAY,[lastdate], [date]) 
            else NULL end AS [win-recency]                                         but the only problem is that I don't want the max-date as last-date be the current day! this algorithm considers the current date too! and if the current date's place=1; then it returns NULL for current date!

Comment: sorry, I'm confused, the query above should return the same as your second image. In particular I made sure that indeed in row 4 of your example, a NULL is returned. Could you post another image with the current results and point what is different? And what do you mean by "current date"? usually that means "today".

Comment: If I understand you correctly, replacing MAX with MIN should give what you want. MAX picks the most recent win and MIN picks the oldest win.

Comment: no it should be Max, it's right for all conditions; the exception only occurs when more than one 1 occurs in subsequent rows. I think I should change IF/Case statement and add another condition such as : when [date]=[lastdate] then ????? .   anyway thanks a lot; you helped me a lot :)

Comment: no problem. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but if MIN works for the last example I think it also works for the original example. Anyway, if you are happy with it, it's also fine for me :)

Comment: yeah; I'll try both MIN and MAX. by the way I made a mistake in the picture that I sent in comments (in win-recency column)! I delete it. this is the result that I want : http://www.8pic.ir/images/01677270733661367637.png      thanks a lot

Comment: So, it's a running count that restarts when a new win happens?

Comment: for sql 2008: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb380/2       I have SQL 2008 installed in my laptop.

Comment: wow; great; thanks a lot :) you are very good at sql; sorry if I confused you at first . Best Wishes