# COUNT of rows satisfying a condition (resets at rows with specific conditions)

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a question about writing query in sql (in continue of my previous question: [subtract values of two rows and inserting it into a new column (not subsequent rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895676/subtract-values-of-two-rows-and-inserting-it-into-a-new-column-not-subsequent-r)):

I want to write a query that calculate the number of times that a user had won a competition before the current time, the condition of winning is place=1 ; I want the result in a new column (win-frequency) and the value of [win-frequency] changes when a new winning happens.  in the following picture, I calculated win-frequency manually.

http://www.8pic.ir/images/54691148512772358477.jpg

I write the following query, but I got error:

```
SELECT [user-name], 
   submissions,
   [date],
   place,
   recency,
   [win-recency],
   COUNT( SELECT [date] FROM [top-design1]] td1
          WHERE td1.[user-name] = [top-design1].[user-name]
          AND  place=1
          AND [date]< [top-design1].[date]
          ORDER BY [date] DESC) as win-frequency
        )
FROM [top-design1]
```

this is the sql fiddle: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ec5f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fix the brackets `)` and `[`, remove the `ORDER BY` from the correlated subquery, and escape the column name `[win-frequency]`. It should be this way:

```
SELECT [user-name], 
   submissions,
   [date],
   place,
   recency,
   [win-recency],
   (SELECT COUNT([date])
    FROM [top-design1] td1
    WHERE td1.[user-name] = [top-design1].[user-name]
      AND  place = 1
      AND [date] < [top-design1].[date]
    ) as [win-frequency]
FROM [top-design1];
```

- [**Updated SQL Fiddle Demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ec5f/10)

Comment: @PotentialScientist - You're welcome any time :) Glad I could help :)